# Elastic Transcoder Boto3 Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-elastic-transcoder

I am tearing my hear out with the following error when trying to use Elastic Transcoder invoked from Lambda via a python function Boto3. The  error in Cloudwatch Logs is: "An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the CreateJob operation: 1 validation error detected: Value 'PIPE' at 'pipelineId' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: ^\d{13}-\w{6}$"

As per my code, I specify the name of my Pipeline ID in Elastic Transcoder as PIPE and it doesn't like the characters used. I have tried a few other combinations such as a number and dot. Has anyone had this error and solved it before? I have used AWS example code as my starting point. Thanks in advance!

```
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    # Job configuration settings. Set these values before running the script.
    pipeline_id = 'PIPE'         # ID of an existing Elastic Transcoder pipeline
    input_file = 'ChiliChallenge.mp4'          # Name of an existing file in the S3 input bucket
    output_file = 'output'  # Desired root name of the transcoded output files

    # Other job configuration settings. Optionally change as desired.
    output_file_prefix = 'elastic-transcoder-samples/output/hls/'  # Prefix for all output files
    segment_duration = '2'                                         # Maximum segment duration in seconds

    # Elastic Transcoder presets used to create HLS multi-segment
    # output files in MPEG-TS format
    hls_64k_audio_preset_id = '1351620000001-200071'    # HLS Audio 64kb/second
    hls_0400k_preset_id = '1351620000001-200050'        # HLS 400k
    hls_0600k_preset_id = '1351620000001-200040'        # HLS 600k
    hls_1000k_preset_id = '1351620000001-200030'        # HLS 1M
    hls_1500k_preset_id = '1351620000001-200020'        # HLS 1.5M
    hls_2000k_preset_id = '1351620000001-200010'        # HLS 2M

    # Define the various outputs
    outputs = [
        {
            'Key': 'hlsAudio/' + output_file,
            'PresetId': hls_64k_audio_preset_id,
            'SegmentDuration': segment_duration,
        },
        {
            'Key': 'hls0400k/' + output_file,
            'PresetId': hls_0400k_preset_id,
            'SegmentDuration': segment_duration,
        },
        {
            'Key': 'hls0600k/' + output_file,
            'PresetId': hls_0600k_preset_id,
            'SegmentDuration': segment_duration,
        },
        {
            'Key': 'hls1000k/' + output_file,
            'PresetId': hls_1000k_preset_id,
            'SegmentDuration': segment_duration,
        },
        {
            'Key': 'hls1500k/' + output_file,
            'PresetId': hls_1500k_preset_id,
            'SegmentDuration': segment_duration,
        },
        {
            'Key': 'hls2000k/' + output_file,
            'PresetId': hls_2000k_preset_id,
            'SegmentDuration': segment_duration,
        },
    ]

    # Define the playlist
    playlists = [
        {
            'Name': 'hls_' + output_file,
            'Format': 'HLSv3',
            'OutputKeys': [x['Key'] for x in outputs]
        }
    ]

    # Create an HLS job in Elastic Transcoder
    etc_client = boto3.client('elastictranscoder')
    response = etc_client.create_job(PipelineId=pipeline_id,
                                         Input={'Key': input_file},
                                         Outputs=outputs,
                                         OutputKeyPrefix=output_file_prefix,
                                         Playlists=playlists)

    # Output job ID and exit. Do not wait for the job to finish.
    print(f'Created Amazon Elastic Transcoder HLS job {job_info["Id"]}')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On entering your regex at https://regexr.com/

I think your pipeline_id should be of the format:

1704334089176-jhNzi6 (13 digits followed by a '-' followed by 6 alphanumeric chars).

Do check your Pipeline ID in Elastic Transcoder to confirm the correct pipe ID. Maybe this can help you find out the correct ID:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/latest/developerguide/list-pipelines.html

Comment: Thank you! I have updated my code to include the pipeline id instead of the name.

Answer (score 1):

Why have you set PipelineId to 'PIPE'? The pipeline ID is not an identifier that you choose; it's the ID of an existing pipeline resource, one that you should have previously created using [create_pipeline()](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/elastictranscoder.html#ElasticTranscoder.Client.create_pipeline) or equivalent and to which the Elastic Transcoder service assigned a unique pipeline ID of the form `^\d{13}-\w{6}$`.